# Live Agent REST API Availability

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console

I found the possibility to get the Availability of the Live Agent via REST API and it works fine.

I noticed when I set a live agent on Online, it returns Availability: true.
Nice, this is how I expect it.

But when I set the live agent on Offline again, I still receive the same response, only like a minute(or 2) later, the availability is false.

Does somebody know why this is? Or maybe has a solution for a better check?

Goal: Show a message in my Einstein Bot based on if there is a Live Agent available or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is ever looking for the answer, 'Availability' shows as 'True' if you're using older version of 'X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION' in headers to check for agent availability.  I've verified by switching between current (54.0) to old (43.0) API and I can see the discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to the Salesforce corner of SE! Could you please edit your answer to clarify? I don't know if you mean that in older versions it shows `true` for some time after no agent is actually available (as OP stated), and that newer versions flip that value correctly to `false` immediately? Or if you mean that newer versions do not show `true` in some other context?

Comment: It seems that when Live Agent API is called using older API version, it falsely returns 'True' for availability and at times it doesn't return 'True' which means agents are not available.  But with newer API versions (54.0 in my case), this bug doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Latest version didnt help us.
We always see response as available=true

PFA:

[image]

OmniSupervisor shows No Online Agents.

[image]

Another difficulty is to frequently update the version whenever new version is released. How do any third party system leveraging salesforce api track this version change?
**If Salesforce can fix this version issue, would be of much help.**